# Quarkus and reactive datasources - Error Multiple matching properties for name "datasource.url"

Tags: spring-mvc, quarkus

I have a problem connecting to the postgres database using `PgPool` and `ResulSet`, then the Statement of sql. Here is my class of service.

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.ApplicationScope;

    //import io.vertx.reactivex.pgclient.PgPool;
    import io.vertx.axle.pgclient.PgPool;
    import ml.kalansow.domain.StudentFees;
    import ml.kalansow.service.KalansowService;

    @Service
    @ApplicationScope
    public class StudentFeesService implements KalansowService {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudentFeesService.class);

        PgPool client;

        // ----Constructor------------------------------------------

        public StudentFeesService() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        };

        // ------------------------------Method---------------------------------
        @Override
        public String getServiceName() {

            return this.getClass().getName();
        }

        public void processGetFeesDetails(HttpSession session) {

            String strStudentId = (String) session.getAttribute("StudentId");
            StudentFees studentFees = new StudentFees();

            if (strStudentId != null) {
                // This is mandatory before calling the next method
                studentFees.setStudentId(strStudentId);

                populateFeesInfo(studentFees);
                session.setAttribute("studentFees", studentFees);
            } else {

                LOG.error("Student Id is null");
            }

        }

        private void populateFeesInfo(StudentFees studentFees) {

            String strStudentI = studentFees.getStudentId();
            io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            StringBuffer sbQuery = new StringBuffer();
            sbQuery.append("SELECT * FROM STUDENT_FEES WHERE STUDENT_I=");
            sbQuery.append("" + strStudentI + "''");

            if (strStudentI != null) {
                //connection = DatabaseService.getDBConnection();
                connection=(io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.Connection) client.getConnection();
                try {
                    statement = ((Connection) connection).createStatement();
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sbQuery.toString());
                    resultSet.next();
                    studentFees.setJanAcad(resultSet.getString("JAN_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setFebAcad(resultSet.getString("FEB_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setMarAcad(resultSet.getString("MAR_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setAprAcad(resultSet.getString("APR_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setMayAcad(resultSet.getString("MAY_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setJunAcad(resultSet.getString("JUN_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setJulAcad(resultSet.getString("JUL_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setAugAcad(resultSet.getString("AUG_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setSepAcad(resultSet.getString("SEP_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setOctAcad(resultSet.getString("OCT_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setNovAcad(resultSet.getString("NOV_ACAD"));
                    studentFees.setDecAcad(resultSet.getString("DEC_ACAD"));

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    /*DatabaseService.closeDBConnection(statement, resultSet);
                    DatabaseService.realeaseDBConnection();*/

                    client.close();
                }
            } else {
                LOG.error("Student id is null");
            }

        }

    }
```

My application properties file contain  datasource properties

> quarkus.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
>     quarkus.reactive-datasource.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
>     quarkus.reactive-datasource.username=test
>     quarkus.reactive-datasource.password=test

And console is here

> ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching properties for name "datasource.url" property was matched by both public java.util.Optional io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceRuntimeConfig.url and public java.util.Optional io.quarkus.reactive.pg.client.runtime.DataSourceConfig.url. This is likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that both define the same properties (e.g. including both reactive and blocking database extensions)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.addMember(PatternMapBuilder.java:71)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.addGroup(PatternMapBuilder.java:60)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.addMember(PatternMapBuilder.java:85)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.addGroup(PatternMapBuilder.java:60)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.makePatterns(PatternMapBuilder.java:35)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.BuildTimeConfigurationReader.(BuildTimeConfigurationReader.java:107)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:174)
>                   at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:85)
>                   at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:114)
>                   at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:178)
>               at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:96)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both the Agroal extension and the Reactive datasources together for the time being.

We are discussing possible ways to fix that here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/quarkus-dev/3r0lquVsUsc/DVxX7SvQAQAJ .

But for now, your only choice is to use either one or the other.

Comment: If I want to choose reactive, as it should be done, since I modified my properties file this way, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: quarkus.reactive-datasource.url

Comment: or quarkus.datasource.rx.url

Comment: I am follow this https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-postgres-client

Comment: As mentioned above, you cannot use `quarkus-agroal` and `quarkus-reactive...` extensions together. So you need to get rid of Agroal (and any other extension requiring it such as Hibernate ORM) and only use the reactive one.